# Can't figure out how to install Python package decoder.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

Python n00b here trying to install [decoder.py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/decoder.py/1.5XB) via pip.

I see it exists when I search for it

```
$ pip search decoder.py
decoder.py (1.5XB)  - Cross-platform Python module for decoding compressed audio files
```

But i can't seem to install it.

```
$ pip install decoder.py
Collecting decoder.py
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement decoder.py (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for decoder.py
$ pip install decoder.py==1.5XB
Collecting decoder.py==1.5XB
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement decoder.py==1.5XB (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for decoder.py==1.5XB
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This package doesn't provide any downloadable source code on PyPI.

You can download it from http://www.brailleweb.com/cgi-bin/python.py (**this link was provided by authors on pypi, proceed with caution**).

Answer (score 0):

Author of decoder.py here. :D

I am sorry for inconvenience. pip was able to grab decoder.py from brailleweb.com before. It was unable to install it though because I didn't provide a setup script. I didn't do it primarily because people might like to choose which external decoders they would like to use and perhaps don't want to install them into their's Python site-packages directory on Windows.
So I settled for manual installation instead. You aren't first who complained about it and that's why  next version will have the setup script at least.

The new version is coming out soon. I am sorry to say development is slower than I anticipated but new version will be ready sooner or later. :D

Cheers!